# Extjs grid panel with checkboxes

Tags: gridview, extjs

How i can create ExtJs grid panel with checkboxes like [here](http://grab.by/30t6).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In Ext 3.4, you'll want to use the `Ext.grid.CheckColumn` plugin as demonstrated in the EditorGrid sample included in the framework download.

In Ext 4+ there is a CheckColumn type built-in (`xtype: 'checkcolumn'`).

Here's an example of what the column config looks like for a checkbox column in version 4+:

```
  xtype: 'checkcolumn',
  header: 'Active?',
  dataIndex: 'active', // model property to bind to
  width: 60,
  editor: {
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    cls: 'x-grid-checkheader-editor'
  }
```

Comment: It works for me, but I can not check any row. Also the link seems to be broken again.

Comment: Ugh. I wish the Sencha folks would learn about 301 redirects... Fixed again, for now.

Comment: This is not true. In Ext 4.1 there is no checkcolumn

Comment: @OliverWatkins Here is a link to the CheckColumn docs in Ext 4.1: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.ux.CheckColumn  - Thanks for the downvote!

Answer (score 3):

How about using this?

```
var checkBoxSelMod = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel();
```

:-D

You can switch position of check box by placing the selection model object at desired position in the column list. This will allow you to place multiple checkboxes in the grid.

Comment: How do you move the checkBoxSelMod around in the column list?

Comment: For e.g., if you want it in the 3 column, then put checkBoxSelModel in the 3rd position in the cols attribute.