# ExtJs 4 Grid Selection Model

Tags: extjs4

I'm using CheckboxModel for my grid. How can I disable checking selected row by mouse click on row (not on check box). In other words how can I separate selection rows by click on row and click on checkboxes? I know about checkOnly in CheckboxModel, but if I enable it I can't select row by mouse click on row

Comment: Your question is very confusing. You are asking how to disable row select on row click, but then you say that's not what you want

Comment: I want to disable checking checkbox when I click on row (not on checkbox)

Comment: it seems like you are going into wrong direction, if you want to seperate row selection and checkbox selection then don't use CheckboxSelection instead use RowSelection and a column whose renderer  will be a checkbox so checkbox selection will not interfere with row selection

Comment: Ok, thank you. Tell me please how can I add column with checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

> it seems like you are going into wrong direction, if you want to
>   seperate row selection and checkbox selection then don't use
>   CheckboxSelection instead use RowSelection and a column whose renderer
>   will be a checkbox so checkbox selection will not interfere with row
>   selection

To add column with the checkbox you need to use Ext.ux.CheckColumn column and include it in the list of columns, the dataIndex associated with that checkcolumn should be a boolean which will store checked/unchecked state of that column

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        header: 'Header',
        dataIndex: 'field'
    }]
});
```

and also make sure that `Ext.ux` library is included

**References:**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2431312/1237812
2. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/cell-editing.html
3. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/cell-editing.js
4. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ux.CheckColumn